# How do I say "thank you for cheering me up (yesterday/the other day)"?

Tags: translation

Thank you for cheering me up (yesterday/the other day).

Is it:

> 谢谢你那天我加油?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"to cheer someone up" is different from "to cheer someone on"

'to cheer someone up' = '鼓舞 someone'

'to cheer someone on' = '替 someone 打气' or '替 someone 加油'

- "Thank you for **cheering** me **up** yesterday" means 多谢你昨天鼓舞我" (or 鼓励我)*-  you say or do something to make someone feel better*
- "Thank you for **cheering** me **on** yesterday" means "多谢你昨天替我打气 (or 加油)-  *When you cheer someone on, you shout loudly in order to encourage them*

Answer (score 2):

You need insert 给 or 替 to your Chinese sentence to denote the sense '**for**'.

> 谢谢你那天 给/替 我加油?

In practice, I probably add a 来 or 能来 as well.

> 谢谢你那天来给我加油? or 谢谢你那天能来给我加油?

Note. I'm not discerning about the difference between **cheer up** and **cheer on** in English. So, I just blindly assume you meant 加油 in Chinese.